# Arduino LCD display does not display text

Tags: arduino, lcd

I'm using LCD for the first time and I'm unable to make it work. It lights the background but it does not show any text. I tried three times from the beginning, each time with a different tutorial, and none of the solutions worked. Is there any mistake in my [wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyvOe.jpg) that I do not see?

Code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>


LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(millis()/1000);
}
```

Here are the links to the tutorials I used:

- https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld
- http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-an-LCD-displays-Arduino-Tutorial/
- https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-11-lcd-displays-1/breadboard-layout

I also attached a link to the picture with my wiring.

[image: Picture]

Comment: Did you adjust the contrast?

Comment: I did using potentiometer knob but it didn't helped either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just need to adjust contrast. I dont understand why you have tkat pot connected to + and - and center pin is left over. Also, get better wires. Connect that pot to contrast pins and try to adjust it.

Comment: It Works!  Thank You for Your advice. Stefan M pointed out that I do not have center pin connected and I took his advice, connected it to contrast but it still didn't work. After Your comment I took another look on my potentiometer and connected it in a different way(so its not connected to + and -). Now it works how it should.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to look for each wiring as all your cables are bent and twisted. From [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-11-lcd-displays-1/breadboard-layout) I can see that the big yellow cable is meant to lead to the slider. You left the end of it on the left-hand-side of the breadboard, which is NOT connected to the right-hand side.

This means: Connect your red cable on the lower left side (in the column "H") to your slider in column "D", between the other two cables.

Comment: Thank You for fast response, I changed cable You mentioned but it still do not work